# I want to move from one address to another in flutter

Tags: flutter, redirect

Here is part of an example from "webview_flutter 2.0.13".

```dart
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
           // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
           actions: <Widget>[
             NavigationControls(_controller.future),
             SampleMenu(_controller.future),
           ],
         ),
         // We're using a Builder here so we have a context that is below the Scaffold
         // to allow calling Scaffold.of(context) so we can show a snackbar.
         body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
           return WebView(
             initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
             javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
             onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
               _controller.complete(webViewController);
             },
             onProgress: (int progress) {
               print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
             },
             javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
               _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
             },
             navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
               if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                 print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                 return NavigationDecision.prevent;
               }
               print('allowing navigation to $request');
               return NavigationDecision.navigate;
             },
             onPageStarted: (String url) {
               print('Page started loading: $url');
             },
             onPageFinished: (String url) {
               print('Page finished loading: $url'); // ***********************
               if (url.toLowerCase().contains('aaaaa')) {
                 controller.data!.loadUrl("https://other_domain"); 
               }  // **********************************************************
             },
             gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
           );
         }),
         floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
       );
     }
```

> Please note the "********" part...
> I'm trying to go to another domain when the webview contains "aaaa".

Please teach me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
 late WebViewController _con;
    @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(
               title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
             ),
             // We're using a Builder here so we have a context that is below the Scaffold
             // to allow calling Scaffold.of(context) so we can show a snackbar.
             body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
               return WebView(
                 initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
                 javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                 onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                     _con = webViewController;
                 },
                 onProgress: (int progress) {
                   print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
                 },
                 javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                   _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
                 },
                 navigationDelegate: (action)async {
                   if (action.url.toLowerCase().contains('aaaaa')) {
                        await _con.loadUrl(action.url);
                     return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                   } 
                 },
                 onPageStarted: (String url) {
                   print('Page started loading: $url');
                 },
                 onPageFinished: (String url) {},
                 gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
               );
             }),
           );
         }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).